# Trouble searching for C (and D, Go, etc.) jobs

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, search

I've seen a few jobs C programming jobs, but clicking on the [c] tag returns no results. Is your search backend silently ignoring single-char search terms?

On a related note, I can't search for (worst case example) jobs tagged [go] by entering it in brackets they way I can on StackOverflow. This just does a full-text search on the word "go" which is useless :(

Comment: http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs#/tag/c is effectively empty. But the tag exists.

Comment: hopefully that's [status-bydesign].  `C` jobs? *shudders*

Comment: Wise guys :) Oh well, more C jobs for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks, you should be able to find [single-letter tags](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs#/tag/c) now. It was related to SQL Server's full-text "stoplist", which ignores most single-letter words.

We are not supporting the [go] syntax just yet on careers, since our tag system is not a strict as SO's. A tag search on Careers is really a full-text search, since our employer customers are not as accustomed to the importance of tagging. We make it fuzzy by design.

(I can see why "go" would be problematic tho, we'll see what we can do.)

Comment: Ok, that helps. I say you should allow searches like [go] and [c], for job hunters if not employers (besides, I'd prefer to work for someone who actually reads the search help!)

Comment: Appears to be broken again. http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/tag/c returns zero jobs even when I clicked on the tag from a job listing like [this one](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/13530/senior-software-engineer-trafficland?a=fZ6rQhG). Help !

Comment: Ick. Sorry. Working on it...

Comment: Still borken a month later :(

Comment: OK, this should be a bit better for C: http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/tag/c. Still working on R.