# Careers search for "golang" returns results unrelated to golang or [go]

Tags: bug, jobs, search

A Careers search for "golang" the text:

http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs?searchTerm=golang&location=united+states&range=20&distanceUnits=Km&allowsremote=true

appears to return results unrelated to golang:

http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/104305/front-end-developer-go-fish-digital?searchTerm=golang&offset=1&distanceunits=Km&location=united%20states&range=20

> Front End Developer
> $60,000 - 75,000
> Go Fish Digital
>
>     Tysons, VA
>     Remote
>
> jquery css php mysql html5
>
>     Mid-Level

As "[golang]" the tag expands to the "[go]" tag, I guess one would, in fact, expect that jobs tagged w/ "[go]" should be included, too, however, I think it's a bug to parse the input as a tag, yet use the results of such expansion to search for stuff completely unrelated to "golang" the text or "[go]" the tag, resulting in a whole bunch of false positives.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trouble searching for C (and D, Go, etc.) jobs](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91986/trouble-searching-for-c-and-d-go-etc-jobs)

Comment: @NathanTuggy, absolutely not a duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/91986/221016, please read the description again -- I'm not searching for "go" at all, yet that;s what I;m getting.

Comment: As far as I can tell, it's a dupe because they're caused by the same underlying issue: full-text search instead of tag search. The fact that [golang] gets transformed to [go] is certainly an interesting wrinkle, but once that happens, the rest plays out identically.

Comment: @NathanTuggy but the other one was fixed, in such cases of a bug that happens again after being fixed, it's OK to post a new bug report. (That said, MSE is no longer the meta site of Careers, so it's off topic here.)

Comment: @NathanTuggy, did you miss the fact that I'm not doing a tag search, nor a full-text search on "go", but on "golang" instead?  Since when is the ASCII text of "golang" is supposed to match "go", "going" and whatnot?

Comment: @cnst: No, I didn't miss that. Your bug report indicates that you found it acceptable for [golang] to become [go], and I'd assume you found it acceptable for "golang" to become [golang] (which is the standard behavior across all SE search). Given that, the only remaining part of the behavior you can object to in general is the one described in the previous bug.

Comment: @NathanTuggy, but "golang" doesn't become "[golang]" -- put the brackets in the original URL, and you'll get only 10% of the original results

Comment: @cnst: Ah, well you can edit that into the question and make it distinct now!

Comment: well, in retrospect, I guess I see why you found "should be included" confusing; it should probably be a "could" instead.